# Unable to redirect stdout/stderr to log file

Tags: shell, io-redirection, time, stdout, stderr

I have a script `tmp.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello
sleep 3
echo 3
```

I want to log the script running time (as well as script stdout) to a log file.

```
user$ time ./tmp.sh >& log.tmp

real    0m3.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

does not work.

```
user$ time ./tmp.sh 2>&1 log.tmp
hello
3

real    0m3.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
```

this also does not work.

What is the correct way to log the output of `time` command to log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time` builtin of `bash` shows timing info on STDERR after the command after it (the actual one) returns. So unless you grouped them and pass the STDERR of the group to a file, only the actual command's STDERR will be redirected to the file and the file will be closed when command returns (prior to `time` shows its info).

You can use command grouping, redirecting both STDOUT and STDERR:

```
{ time ./tmp.sh ;} &>log.tmp
```

Or run in a subshell:

```
( time ./tmp.sh ) &>log.tmp
```

**Example:**

```
$ { time sleep 1 ;} 2>time.log
$ cat time.log 

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s


$ ( time sleep 1 ) 2>time.log
$ cat time.log 

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```